# PHP Accessing mysqli_fetch_assoc value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have been trying to store the results of a MySQL query in a PHP array, however I have been struggling to access the values after they have been stored.

I used this to store the query:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($array, $row);
}
```

Which when showing the array with `var_dump` gives an output similar to this, just with more values:

```
array(147) { [0]=> array(1) { ["TABLE_NAME"]=> string(8) "_3085515" } }
```

I want to be able to access the value with the _NUMBER, but I can't figure out how to do this?

Comment: `$array[0]['TABLE_NAME']` …?

Comment: @CBroe That works, thanks! I had tried this, but got ['TABLE_NAME'] and [0] the opposite way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st :**  Declare the variable as a `array`

```
   $array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       array_push($array, $row);
    }
```

**2nd :**   Access the value like this

```
 $array[0]['TABLE_NAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like that.

```
$array = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   array_push($array, $row);
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: Need to declare variable instead of use it directly.

Comment: So? How does that answer the question?